# How to save states of an html layout in JQuery or any other server side language?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a web application similar to [canva](https://www.canva.com) and I want to add the functionality that when I close/exit web browser after making any kind of design, my application should save all the states or html layout and when I open/run web browser again even I clear my cache it should redirect me to recent design layouts and all html elements.
Is it possible in JQuery? or if there is any other approach please suggest me.
Thank you :) 
[here is my application view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqB3y.png)

Comment: No. You require a server side language, (such as PHP), to do this.

Comment: you can use browser local storage

Comment: Thank you for your response Chris and Felix.

Comment: Felix!
does browser's local storage remains even I clear cache?

Comment: and is it possible to store data in browser's storage in JQuery?